# How to get Docker as option for Python Interpreter in Pycharm?

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

I'm trying to setup debugging for a Python/Docker application (anonlink) using the instructions here:

https://anonlink-entity-service.readthedocs.io/en/v1.15.0/debugging.html

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#docker-compose-remote

I've installed the Docker plug in:

[image]

I've created the Docker instance:

[image]

However, Docker does not appear as an option for python interpreter:

[image]

How do I add Docker as an interpreter so I can enable debugging of this Docker application?

Comment: Looks like you are using PyCharm Community and Docker-based interpreters are only supported in Professional.

Comment: I believe you are correct sir.  I've moved to PyCharm Professional and everything regarding this seems to be working.  I think there is documentation that suggests there is a way to get this to work with Community edition but moving to Professional was a lot easier.